# How can I drag and drop from Spotlight search results on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I'd like to hit `Cmd-Space`, type my query, and then from the list, drag a file to my Desktop or my browser or whatever.  The best I have is that with the file highlighted, I can hit `Cmd-I` and then drag the preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> click the item in the Spotlight list. This will reveal the item in a Finder. From there you can drag the file wherever you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Lion. However, it currently seems a bit buggy and I can't figure out how to move the file, only copy it.